# Numpy - slicing 2d row or column vector from array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice, reshape

I'm trying to find a neat little trick for slicing a row/column from a 2d array and obtaining an array of `(col_size x 1)` or `(1 x row_size)`.

Is there an easier way than to use `numpy.reshape()` after every slicing?

Cheers,
Stephan

Comment: Can you provide an example of expected input and output please? Do you want to obtain a 1D array or 2D array?

Comment: Sure! Let's say I have an array like `np.ones((2,40))`. From this array I want to slice a whole row in the form of an `np.array((1,40))`. The result should be a 2d array

Comment: Use np.newaxis or None to insert a new axis

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can slice and insert a new axis in one single operation. For example, here's a 2D array:

```
>>> a = np.arange(1, 7).reshape(2, 3)
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

To slice out a single *column* (returning array of shape `(2, 1)`), slice with `None` as the third dimension:

```
>>> a[:, 1, None]
array([[2],
       [5]])
```

To slice out a single *row* (returning array of shape `(1, 3)`), slice with `None` as the second dimension:

```
>>> a[0, None, :]
array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: No problem! Indexing/reshaping takes a while to wrap your head around (at least it did for me), but makes sense after a bit of practice. The [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) are pretty good for explaining what's happening here (the *basic slicing* section).

Comment: Curiously I never thought to combine the indexing with the `None` addition.  I guess it is just the force of habit, using `None` to expand the dimensions of an existing array.  And it is faster.

Answer (score 7):

Make the index a slice, list or array

```
    X[[0],:]
    X[0:1,4]
```

But there's nothing wrong with `reshape` other than the fact that it requires typing.  It isn't slow.  `[None,:]` is a nice short hand for it.

Use of a list index may be the shortest, but it does produce a copy (a plus or minus?) and is slower

For `(100,100)` integer array:

```
In [487]: timeit x[[50],:]
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.3 µs per loop  # slowest

In [488]: timeit x[50:51,:]
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.24 µs per loop   # slice indexing is fast

In [489]: timeit x[50,:].reshape(1,-1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.29 µs per loop  # minimal time penalty

In [490]: timeit x[50,:][None,:]
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.55 µs per loop

In [543]: timeit x[None,50,:]          # **best**
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.76 µs per loop
```

One test for copy is to compare the data buffer pointer with the original.

```
In [492]: x.__array_interface__['data']
Out[492]: (175920456, False)
In [493]: x[50,:].__array_interface__['data']
Out[493]: (175940456, False)
In [494]: x[[50],:].__array_interface__['data']
Out[494]: (175871672, False)    # different pointer
In [495]: x[50:51,:].__array_interface__['data']
Out[495]: (175940456, False)
In [496]: x[50,:][None,:].__array_interface__['data']
Out[496]: (175940456, False)
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm implementing a scalable neural network, scalable in terms of layer sizes. With `reshape` I had to access very often different instance attributes (e.g. the layer sizes). Finally to get it right: when I use `a[0, None, :]` to slice a row from `array` a, will it then return a copy?

Comment: `[0, None, :]` returns a view.

Answer (score 5):

How about this nice and easy way?

```
In [73]: arr = (np.arange(5, 25)).reshape(5, 4)

In [74]: arr
Out[74]: 
array([[ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16],
       [17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 24]])

# extract column 1 as a column vector
In [79]: col1 = arr[:, [0]]
In [80]: col1.shape
Out[80]: (5, 1)

In [81]: col1
Out[81]: 
array([[ 5],
       [ 9],
       [13],
       [17],
       [21]])


# extract row 1 as a row vector
In [82]: row1 = arr[[0], :]

In [83]: row1.shape
Out[83]: (1, 4)

In [84]: row1
Out[84]: array([[5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

Comment: Thank you for the clean and detailed answer! But haven't you noticed that the question is more than two years old? Cheers :)

Comment: @neurotronix I just realized that. Anyway, for pedagogical reasons, time never matters ;)

Comment: Very true, thanks for taking the time to put up an answer!