# How to model data for tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, tensor

I have data of the form :

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G
1   0   0   1   0   0   1
1   0   0   1   0   0   1
1   0   0   1   0   1   0
1   0   1   0   1   0   0
...               
1   0   1   0   1   0   0
0   1   1   0   0   0   1
0   1   1   0   0   0   1
0   1   0   1   1   0   0
0   1   0   1   1   0   0
```

`A,B,C,D` are my inputs and `E,F,G` are my outputs. I wrote the following code in Python using TensorFlow:

```
from __future__ import print_function
#from random import randint

import numpy as np
import tflearn
import pandas as pd


data,labels =tflearn.data_utils.load_csv('dummy_data.csv',target_column=-1,categorical_labels=False, n_classes=None)

 print(data)
 # Build neural network
 net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 4])
 net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
 net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
 net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 3, activation='softmax')
 net = tflearn.regression(net)

 # Define model
 model = tflearn.DNN(net)
 #Start training (apply gradient descent algorithm)
 data_to_array = np.asarray(data)
 print(data_to_array.shape)
 #data_to_array= data_to_array.reshape(6,9)
 print(data_to_array.shape)
 model.fit(data_to_array, labels, n_epoch=10, batch_size=3, show_metric=True)
```

I am getting an error which says:

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape `(3, 6)` for Tensor `'InputData/X:0'`, which has shape `'(?, 4)'`

I am guessing this is because my input data has 7 columns (0...6), but I want the input layer to take only the first four columns as input and predict the last 3 columns in the data as output. How can I model this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data's in a numpy format, then the first 4 columns are taken with a simple slice:

```
data[:,0:4]
```

The `:` means "all rows", and `0:4` is a range of values `0,1,2,3`, the first 4 columns.

If the data isn't in a numpy format, just convert it to a numpy format so you can slice easily.

Here's a related article on numpy slices: [Numpy - slicing 2d row or column vector from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764200/numpy-slicing-2d-row-or-column-vector-from-array)

Comment: But, where do I feed the the last 3 columns (E,F,G) which are my outputs ?

Comment: You'll certainly need to declare an input for your labels as well.